# Cannot use GraphQL queries in React - has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs, redux, graphql

I have a React application that connects to a back-end Laravel application that has a GraphQL layer on top of it.

I have a GraphQL query as such:

```
http://laravel-quarx.dev/graphql?query=query+getUserNameAndId{users{id,name}}
```

Which will return the following JSON:

`{"data":{"users":[{"id":1,"name":"Admin"},{"id":2,"name":"Saqueib Ansrai"}]}}`

Here is how I fetch this data in React (I am using Redux so I have my call in the Saga):

```
function* fetchProducts(actions) {
    try {
        const response = yield call(fetchApi, {
            method: 'GET',
            url: '?query=query+getUserNameAndId{users{id,name}}',
        });

        yield put(productSuccess(response));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(productFailure(e.response ? e.response.data.message : e));
    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://laravel-quarx.dev/graphql/?query=query+getUserNameAndId{users{id,name}}.
>   Redirect from
>   'http://laravel-quarx.dev/graphql/?query=query+getUserNameAndId{users{id,name}}'
>   to
>   'http://laravel-quarx.dev/graphql?query=query+getUserNameAndId{users{id,name}}'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

[image]

I am unsure as to what I have to do on my server-side application to bypass the CORS limitations, any ideas?

EDIT:

Headers:
[image]

Cors config:

```
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    //Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

Comment: Try using this `https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors`

Comment: @Panther I tried that exact package but still get he same problem.

Comment: Did you set the `config/cors.php` as shown in their github readme page and did you publish the same ? if so can you show the `response` headers for the options request ?

Comment: @Panther Yes I did exactly the same, see edit for the headers.

Comment: Looks like no CORS header is present. Headers like `allowedOrigins`, `allowedHeaders` and `allowedMethods` should be present in the `response` of `options` request. So something is missing either in your config or on the server, which you have to find out.

Comment: If you temporarily need to develop then you can make use of https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi as mentioned by @shytj. But that would allow the requests only on your browser. So you have to enable CORS on the server so that all can use it.

Comment: I have posted my cors config file, does this seem correct? I'm not sure what else I need to do?

Comment: Hmm. Check if you have added the middleware to the routes properly. And finally check if the publish is successful.

Comment: @Panther what do you mean when you say add middleware to the routes? I am using graphql routes not normal Laravel routes

Comment: Check your graphql docs. You can add middleware to it in the config file.

Comment: I have, like this: `'middleware' => ['cors'],` in `config/graphql.php`. Still not working.

Comment: @Panther ??? any ideas?

Comment: Nope. The issue should be only with cors related.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, one is making your application to understand cors, and the second is to disable cors in the fetch options in your apollo client:

```
const link  = new HttpLink({
        uri: 'URI',
        fetchOptions: {
            mode: 'no-cors'
        }
    });
```